# How to draw vertical lines in barplot?

Tags: r

I want to draw a vertical line at specific positions of the x-axis, but the x-positions of the lines aren't correct. How can I solve this ?

```
x <- c(0,0,0,4,5,6)
barplot(x, names.arg=1:length(x))
abline(v=1:length(x), col="red")
abline(v=c(5.5), col="blue")
```

Comment: What are the correct positions?

Comment: I would expect the red lines above the names of the x-axis and the blue line between 5 and 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to stick to `base plot`, you can do the same using `ggplot2` and `geom_vline` function:

```r
library(ggplot2)
x <- c(0,0,0,4,5,6)
d <- data.frame(x)
ggplot(d, aes(x = seq(1:6), y = x))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:6)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1:6, color = "red")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 5.5, color = "blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You have to save the result of `barplot`. Then use those values to plot the vertical lines.

```
x <- c(0,0,0,4,5,6)
bp <- barplot(x, names.arg = seq_along(x))
abline(v = bp, col = "red")
abline(v = 5.5, col = "blue")
```

[image]

Note that the blue line was plotted twice and therefore became violet. So remove the value `5.5` from the first call to `abline`.

```
bp <- barplot(x, names.arg = seq_along(x))
abline(v = bp[bp != 5.5], col = "red")
abline(v = 5.5, col = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: But isn't the blue line at 5, instead of 5.5 ?

Comment: @user No, the values returned by `barplot` are the bars' mid points, it's confusing but that's the way it is with base graphics. For a more intuitive graphics system, see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59619086/8245406) by @dc37.

Answer (score 1):

A key for placing a vertical line at any point on the x-axis is to see the "hidden" coordinates used for the x-axis by barplot().  To see it, the barplot() output should be saved as mentioned in the answer by Rui Barradas.

```
x <- c(0,0,0,4,5,6)
A = barplot(x, names.arg=1:length(x))
A
> A
     [,1]
[1,]  0.7
[2,]  1.9
[3,]  3.1
[4,]  4.3
[5,]  5.5
[6,]  6.7
```

It gives the positions of each bar's middle point.  This explains the vertical line drawn in the chart below:

```
abline(v=5.5, col="blue")
```

[image: Adding a vertical line at the position of 5.5]

To add vertical lines between neighboring bars right at the middle, you can do the following.  Here, we first figured out that the mid-point between the first 2 bars is at position 1.3 (= (07+1.9)/2), that between the last 2 bars is at 6.1, and the distance between two successive mid-points is 1.2 (= 1.9-0.7).

```
abline(v = seq(1.3, 6.1, 1.2))
```

[image: Adding vertical lines between bars]